# Is it undefined behaviour to std::memcpy a struct into a std::vector<char> that has enough capacity?

Tags: c++

Will the following program give undefined behaviour?

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

struct Data
{
    float   a;
    float   b;
    int     z;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> allMyData;

    Data someStuff({.2f,.3f,1});

    allMyData.resize(sizeof(Data));

    std::memcpy(&allMyData[0], &someStuff, sizeof(Data));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd use `allMyData.data()` instead of `&allMyData[0]`

Comment: Your `Data` is a trivial type, so there is no undefined behaviour.     There is implementation defined and/or implementation-specific behaviour, however, since the representation of `float` and `int` types, and of things like `struct` padding are left up to the implementation (and, with some compilers, can be tweaked using compiler settings that affect representation of basic types or `struct` padding).

Comment: You might want to add a `static_assert` See [is_trivially_copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable)

Comment: Note that there is a difference between vector having a "capacity", and vector having a "size". To copy something over elements of a vector, it must have size; capacity is not sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no undefined behavior in the *particular example* you have showed.  However, things would be quite different if `Data` contained pointers to external data, or non-POD class types like standard containers, etc.

Comment: Thanks; I was fairly sure there was no issue with memcpy, but someone recently told me there was a problem https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/gmx91v/long_walkthrough_of_an_entity_component_system/fr6w91l/?context=3 and I wanted to be absolutely sure.

Comment: When in doubt, you could use `std::copy()` instead, which can make use of `std::memcpy()` internally when it knows it is safe to do so.

Comment: you couldn't use std::copy in this instance though, right? The types are different?

Comment: @NeomerArcana it would take some type-casting to pull off, eg: `std::copy(&someStuff, &someStuff+1, reinterpret_cast<Data*>(allMyData.data()));` or `std::copy_n(&someStuff, 1, reinterpret_cast<Data*>(allMyData.data()));` Of course, you could also do `reinterpret_cast<Data&>(allMyData.front()) = someStuff;` or even `new(allMyData.data()) Data(someStuff);`.  There are a lot of questionable ways to copy `someStuff` into your vector.

Comment: in all your examples, the code isn't any safer right? I'm trying to get to the bottom of your recommendation to use `std::copy`. I'm guessing the explicit use of `reinterpret_cast` might be considered to make the intent clearer, but surely the use of `memcpy` makes that same intent clear?

Comment: @NeomerArcana there is a big difference between `memcpy()`'ing `sizeof(object)` number of raw bytes, vs `std::copy()`'ing a whole `object`. `std::copy()` will ensure proper copy semantics for a non-POD `object` type, provided source and destination are constructed properly beforehand.

Comment: so the first case you gave `std::copy(&someStuff, &someStuff+1, reinterpret_cast<Data*>(allMyData.data()));` will ensure that `someStuff` is copied correctly then (the second example wouldn't)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214225/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-neomerarcana).

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between vector's `capacity` and its `size` take for example this code:

```
auto vector = std::vector<float>();
auto array = std::array<float, 4096>();

array.fill(0.5f);
vector.resize(4096);

std::copy(array.begin(), array.end(), vector.data());
```

Here copying contents of `array` like that is perfectly fine because `vector`'s size is 4096 elements - same as array. However, as soon as you do this:

```
auto vector = std::vector<float>();
auto array = std::array<float, 4096>();

array.fill(0.5f);
vector.reserve(4096);

std::copy(array.begin(), array.end(), vector.data());
```

You will run into a lot of trouble because even though you copied `array` into a buffer which can, technically speaking, hold all of the elements, `vector` does not change its `size` so `vector.empty()` would return true and trying to access any of its elements would at best throw a debug exception.